# DataTable - Columns Name: Automatic changing in two different places

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two DataTables. I simply wanna save one of them in the other and then change the column name on my "temporary table".

My problem is that everytime that I change the column name from one table, it is automatically changing in the other.

declaration:

```
public DataTable DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType { get; private set; }
```

How do I get value for the first DataTable:

```
DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType = ((FormProject)Fproject).DataTablefromDataBaseFormProject;
```

How do I copy and change column name:

```
        DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp = DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType;

    DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Columns[column_to_use].ColumnName = "temp";
```

Rest of the code (if needed)

```
    DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp = DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType;

    DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Columns[column_to_use].ColumnName = "temp";
```

// This point! - When I change DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp it is also changing //DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp

```
    if (ReceiveStartDate == null && ReceiveEndDate == null)
    {
        ReceiveStartDate = DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Rows[0][4].ToString();
        ReceiveEndDate = DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Rows[DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Rows.Count-1][4].ToString();
    }

    if (ReceiveNameFile != "All files")
    {


        string query = $"TIME_FORMATTED >='{ReceiveStartDate}' AND TIME_FORMATTED <='{ReceiveEndDate}'";
        DataRow[] result = DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp.Select(query);


        foreach (DataRow row in result)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
            DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.ImportRow(row);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        DataRow[] result = DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType.Select("FILE_NAMES = '"+ ReceiveNameFile + "'");

        foreach (DataRow row in result)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(row[0].ToString());
            DataTableUsedToPlotGraph.ImportRow(row);
        }
    }



}
```

I already debugged several times to see if it is happening in some other place of the code. The moment that it changes the column name, it changes for both DataTables.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have two different `DataTables`(reference type) but only one:

```
DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp = DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType;
```

So if you change one you are changing both. Those are just variables that reference the same object. You can use `DataTable.Copy`:

```
DataTable DataTableUsedToPlotGraphTemp = DataTablefromDataBaseFormDataType.Copy();
```

If you just need an empty table with the same columns you can use `DataTable.Clone`.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5057284/284240) explains it a little bit better:

> For a value type, the value is the information itself. For a reference
>   type, the value is a reference which may be `null` or may be a way of
>   navigating to an object containing the information.
>
> For example, think of a **variable** as like a piece of paper. It could
>   have the value "5" or "false" written on it, but it couldn't have my
>   house... it would have to have directions to my house. Those
>   directions are the equivalent of a reference. In particular, two
>   people could have different pieces of paper containing the same
>   directions to my house - and if one person followed those directions
>   and painted my house red, then the second person would see that change
>   too. If they both just had separate pictures of my house on the paper,
>   then one person colouring their paper wouldn't change the other
>   person's paper at all.